# What does the new `Field.db_default` of django 5 imply ? Should we use it by default or stick with `Field.default`?

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-models

If I understand correctly, `Field.default` do not set a value in the DB, but the value is used when a model instance is created.
On the other hand, `Field.db_default` set the value in the DB.

I am not sure to fully understand the implications that this new option is giving us.

So my question is, which one should be used by default (no pun intended) and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Field.default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) is used to populate your model in python on creation. It can be a constant or a callable. If it's a callable it will be called at the creation of your Model in python.

[`Field.db_default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#db-default) sets the default at the db level. This means when creating your Model in python the field that specifies `db_default` does not have a value.
If the field is None on `save` the database inserts its default value.

The perceived difference is that if you only set the `db_default` your models wont get populated on creation with the default value. Furthermore other rescources that access your database also use this default instead of `default` that only enforces this on the django ORM level.

Which one you choose depends on what you intend to do with your database. Is it only accessed by your django project? Do you need the default value to do some calculation in django?...

It is also possible to use both. In that case `default` gets used for your Models as it gets set on Model creation instead of on `save`

Hope that helped

Comment: You said "The perceived difference is that if you only set the db_default your models wont get populated on creation with the default value. Furthermore other rescources that access your database also use this default instead of default that only enforces this on the django ORM level."

I'm not sure I understand correctly that. If I define a field like `size = models.IntegerField(db_default=2)` on my model but do not provide a value for `size` when I create an instance of my model, the value of `size` will be `None` and not `2` ?

Comment: @Laurent That's right.
But when you save your object, the database engine will give it the default value (2).